# How to find all files and separate results by comma on Unix?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I would like to go from the standard `find` output which is:

```
path/to/file1.yaml
path/to/file2.yaml
path/to/file3.yaml
```

To this:

```
path/to/file1.yaml,path/to/file2.yaml,path/to/file3.yaml
```

What's the simplest way to do that from the command line?

I have tried these things:

```
find . -path '*.yaml' | sed -e 's/\s/,/g'
find . -path '*.yaml' -print0 | sed -e 's/ /,/g'
```

but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is one approach for separating the filenames with commas:

```
find . -path '*.yaml' | tr '\n' ','
```

If the file names do not contain white space, then another approach is:

```
IFS=, echo $(find . -path '*.yaml')
```

In the comments, [Kojiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418413/kojiro) suggests a third approach which preserves whitespace:

```
find . -path '*.yaml' -print0 | tr '\0' ,
```

*Because newlines and commas are allowed in file names, this format may lead to confusion. This format should only be used if you know that your files are sensibly named.*

Comment: You could avoid whitespace confusion with `find . -path '*.yaml' -print0 | tr '\0' ,`.

Comment: @kojiro Excellent.  I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 12):

This will work too :

```
  find . -path '*.yaml' | paste -s -d ',' -
```

Comment: slightly shorter version is also allowed: `find . -path '*.yaml' | paste -sd,`

Comment: I like that this does not produce a trailing comma like the `tr` and `print` approaches do.

Answer (score 3):

both python and perl can do it in one line:

python:

```
find . -path '*.yaml' | python -c 'import sys; print ",".join(sys.stdin.readlines())'
```

perl:

```
find . -path '*.yaml' | perl -e 'print join ",", map {chomp;$_} <STDIN>'
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative that doesn't pipe the output:

```
 find . -name "*.yaml" -printf "%p,"
```

Comment: That includes a final comma after the last file, though. But removing that is easy; `sed 's/,$//'`

Comment: That's true I forgot about the trailing comma.

Comment: or capture it to a variable and perform manipulation to avoid forking a short term process: `${output%,}`.

Answer (score 0):

Globstar is a highly underrated feature of bash 4+. Several shells support similar features.

```
shopt -s globstar
f=( **/*.yaml )
IFS=,
echo "${f[*]}"
```

If you want to avoid having to reset `IFS`, use a subshell or function:

```
join() {
  local IFS="$1"
  shift
  printf '%s\n' "$*"
}
join , **/*.yaml
```

Comment: or: `IFS=, eval 'printf "%s\n" "${f[*]}"'` or to save it in an auxiliary variable: `IFS=, eval 'csv="${f[*]}"'`.